# Generic Android image upload app (like Picup for Iphone)

Tags: android, image, html, upload

I am looking for a way to upload pictures from an HTML5 app on Android (so no Java, no Phonegap, no Titanium etc. ... if possible).

On iOS there is a generic picture upload app called PicUp. You prepare a website in a special way, this website will open picup, picup will handle the file upload for you and then you proceed surfing on the website. Pretty seemless process from the user's point of view.

Now I am looking for a way how to do it on Android.

I already read that as from Android 2.2. the Android OS can handle file uploads and there is nothing to do. But what can I offer people having Android 2.1 and below?

P.S. Here's a video on how the "picup" way looks like in case you are interested:
http://picupapp.com/